# Error while connecting to http service using NT credentials

Tags: java, http, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am connecting to mail server EWS(Webservice) using below code, the connection is successful
But I am getting below warning, could you please help me in understanding what this warning means?

"org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication@:process NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))."

```
   private void initializeCredentials() {


   Credentials credentials = new org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials(userName, password, hostname, "");

   ThreadLocalCredentialsProviderFactory.set(credentials);
```

}

Comment: After some research I could find it is trying to use NEGOTIATE instead of NTLM and then switching to NTLM. Is there any way we can force apache http client to use NTLM instead of NEGOTIATE?